# Looping through list of lists then create a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list containing sublists. I want to loop through all the sublist and extract the data, save them in individual lists then create a dataframe. When I try doing so the values get mixed up....

```
fulllist = [
[
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'Anne'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Wanjohi'},
{'Variable': 'Age',
 'Answer': '50'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'Uganda'}],

[
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'John'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Wagwara'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'Kenya'}
],

[
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'Jeff'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Simboyi'},
{'Variable': 'Age',
 'Answer': '20'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'UK'}],

 [
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'Ken'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Kumbua'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'Tanzania'}
]

]

First_Name = [] 
Middle_Name = []
Age = []
Country = []


for i in range(len(fulllist)):
    try:
        First_Name.append(fulllist[i][0]['Answer'])
        Middle_Name.append(fulllist[i][1]['Answer'])
        Age.append(fulllist[i][2]['Answer'])
        Country.append(fulllist[i][3]['Answer'])
    except IndexError:
        print(i)

print(Age)
print(Country)
```

Comment: maybe this `[{r['Variable']: r['Answer'] for r in row} for row in fulllist]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the order of elements within each sublist in fulllist is consistent, but in some cases, like the second sublist, there is no 'Age' variable, which will leads to an `IndexError`. A more robust approach would be to iterate over each sublist and dynamically extract the values based on the 'Variable' key.

```py
# Initialize empty dictionaries for each variable
data = {'First_Name': [], 'Middle_Name': [], 'Age': [], 'Country': []}

# Iterate over each sublist
for sublist in fulllist:
    # Initialize variables to None
    first_name = middle_name = age = country = None
    # Iterate over each dictionary in the sublist
    for item in sublist:
        if item['Variable'] == 'First_Name':
            first_name = item['Answer']
        elif item['Variable'] == 'Middle_Name':
            middle_name = item['Answer']
        elif item['Variable'] == 'Age':
            age = item['Answer']
        elif item['Variable'] == 'Country':
            country = item['Answer']
    
    # Append values to respective lists
    data['First_Name'].append(first_name)
    data['Middle_Name'].append(middle_name)
    data['Age'].append(age)
    data['Country'].append(country)

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output-

```
  First_Name Middle_Name   Age   Country
0       Anne     Wanjohi    50    Uganda
1       John     Wagwara  None     Kenya
2       Jeff     Simboyi    20        UK
3        Ken      Kumbua  None  Tanzania
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is due to the assumption that each sublist in fulllist will contain the same set of keys in the dictionaries. However, as you can see from your data, not all sublists contain the 'Age' key. To address this, you need to handle cases where the key may be missing.

Here's a modified version of your code that handles the missing keys:

```
import pandas as pd

fulllist = [
    [
        {'Variable': 'First_Name', 'Answer': 'Anne'},
        {'Variable': 'Middle_Name', 'Answer': 'Wanjohi'},
        {'Variable': 'Age', 'Answer': '50'},
        {'Variable': 'Country', 'Answer': 'Uganda'}
    ],
    [
        {'Variable': 'First_Name', 'Answer': 'John'},
        {'Variable': 'Middle_Name', 'Answer': 'Wagwara'},
        {'Variable': 'Country', 'Answer': 'Kenya'}
    ],
    [
        {'Variable': 'First_Name', 'Answer': 'Jeff'},
        {'Variable': 'Middle_Name', 'Answer': 'Simboyi'},
        {'Variable': 'Age', 'Answer': '20'},
        {'Variable': 'Country', 'Answer': 'UK'}
    ],
    [
        {'Variable': 'First_Name', 'Answer': 'Ken'},
        {'Variable': 'Middle_Name', 'Answer': 'Kumbua'},
        {'Variable': 'Country', 'Answer': 'Tanzania'}
    ]
]

First_Name = [] 
Middle_Name = []
Age = []
Country = []

for sublist in fulllist:
    temp_dict = {d['Variable']: d['Answer'] for d in sublist}
    First_Name.append(temp_dict.get('First_Name', ''))
    Middle_Name.append(temp_dict.get('Middle_Name', ''))
    Age.append(temp_dict.get('Age', ''))
    Country.append(temp_dict.get('Country', ''))

df = pd.DataFrame({'First_Name': First_Name, 'Middle_Name': Middle_Name, 'Age': Age, 'Country': Country})
print(df)
```

Comment: Not really. The program that extracts data filters out the missing column so it is not exported into the main list

Comment: ```[
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'John'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Wagwara'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'Kenya'}
]
```

For this one age was not answered so it is missing in this sublist

Comment: Magnificent! It worked as intended!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd


fulllist = [
[
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'Anne'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Wanjohi'},
{'Variable': 'Age',
 'Answer': '50'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'Uganda'}],

[
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'John'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Wagwara'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'Kenya'}
],

[
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'Jeff'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Simboyi'},
{'Variable': 'Age',
 'Answer': '20'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'UK'}],

 [
{'Variable': 'First_Name',
 'Answer': 'Ken'},
{'Variable': 'Middle_Name',
 'Answer': 'Kumbua'},
{'Variable': 'Country',
 'Answer': 'Tanzania'}
]

]

lst = []

# Create a list consists of dictionaries with details of each person
for x in fulllist:
    sub = {}
    for y in x:
        key = y['Variable']
        value = y['Answer']
        sub[key] = value
    lst.append(sub)

# As 'Age' is not available for some of the data mention 'Not available' for them
for x in lst:
    if 'Age' not in x.keys():
        x['Age'] = 'Not available'

# Create modified_dct keys being First_Name and values being a list of other data
modified_dct ={}
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    sub = []
    sub.append(x['Middle_Name'])
    sub.append(x['Age'])
    sub.append(x['Country'])
    modified_dct[x['First_Name']] = sub

# Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(modified_dct, index = ['Middle_Name', 'Age', 'Country'])

print(df)


     
'''Output:
                Anne           John     Jeff            Ken
Middle_Name  Wanjohi        Wagwara  Simboyi         Kumbua
Age               50  Not available       20  Not available
Country       Uganda          Kenya       UK       Tanzania
'''
```

Comment: edited adding the index